# curl - couldn't connect to host

Tags: cocoa, curl

I am using curl in my Cocoa Application to communicate with server. It works fine for sometime. But sometime when it tries to communicate with server using curl it gives response: "Couldn't connect to host". When I got this error my application tries to connect with server after 30 seconds. Sometimes it is connected to server but sometime it continuously gives same error until I restart my Application. After restarting my application it works fine.
Does anybody have any Idea to fix this problem?

Comment: can you reproduce with command line curl?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using cocoa methods for server communication?

Comment: @GradyPlayer I am unable tor reproduce with command line curl because its not appearing for specific scenarios. And I am not using cocoa methods because I have to take care of uploading and downloading bandwidth and also have to communicate through proxy server so I am using curl because it provides these facilities.